# Assembler Error: Mach-O 64 bit does not support absolute 32 bit addresses

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm, mach-o

So I'm learning x86_64 nasm assembly on my mac for fun. After hello world and some basic arithmetic, I tried copying a slightly more advanced hello world program from [this site](http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/not-blog/nasm-programming-for-soen228) and modifying it for 64 bit intel, but I can't get rid of this one error message: `hello.s:53: error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses`. Here is the command I use to assemble and link: `nasm -f macho64 hello.s && ld -macosx_version_min 10.6 hello.o`. And here is the relevant line:

```
cmp rsi, name+8
```

rsi is the register I am using for my index in the loop, and name is a quad word reserved for the user input which is the name, which by this point has already been written.

Here is a part of the code (to see the rest, click the link and go to the bottom, the only difference is that I use 64 bit registers):

```
loopAgain:
mov al, [rsi]           ; al is a 1 byte register
cmp al, 0x0a            ; if al holds an ascii newline...
je exitLoop             ; then jump to label exitLoop

; If al does not hold an ascii newline...
mov rax, 0x2000004      ; System call write = 4
mov rdi, 1              ; Write to stdout = 1
mov rdx, 1              ; Size to write
syscall

inc rsi

cmp rsi, name+8         ; LINE THAT CAUSES ERROR
jl loopAgain
```

Comment: One suggestion:  Try writing the same code in C, compile it with `gcc -S`, and look at the assembly to see how GCC handles it.

Comment: @bdonlan: in the section .bss, I have `name:  resb  8`

Comment: @Nemo: I tried that and I couldn't really make sense of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cmp` instruction does not support a 64-bit immediate operand. As such, you cannot put a 64-bit immediate address reference in one of its operands - load `name+8` into a register then compare to that register.

You can see what instruction encodings are permitted in the [Intel ISA manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/325383.pdf) (warning: huge PDF). As you can see on the entry for CMP, there are `CMP r/m32,
imm32` and `CMP r/m64,
imm32` encodings, which allow for comparisons of a 32-bit immediate with both 32-bit and 64-bit registers, but not a `CMP r/m64, imm64`. There is, however, a `MOV r64, imm64` encoding.

Or even better, use a RIP-relative LEA: Use `default rel` then **`lea r64, [name+8]`**.  This is more efficient and smaller than `mov r64, imm64`.

---

Since nasm is crashing, the failure of `MOV rcx, name+8` is just plain a bug in nasm. Please report it to the nasm devs (after making sure you're using the latest version of nasm; also, check that [this patch](http://repo.or.cz/w/nasm.git?a=commitdiff;h=805266443346f4dcbc387508679a445f47e5f662) doesn't fix the problem). In any case, though, one workaround would be to add a symbol for the end of `name`:

```
name:
    resb 8
name_end:
```

Now simply use `MOV rcx, name_end`. This has the advantage of not needing to update the referents when the size of `name` changes. Alternately you could use a different assembler, such as the clang or GNU binutils assemblers.

---

Discussion in comments points out that Linux can use a symbol address as a 32-bit immediate.  This is true only in non-PIE executables which are linked with a base address in the low 2GiB of virtual address space.  But MacOS chooses to put the image base address above 4GiB so you can't use `mov r32, imm32` or `cmp r64, sign_extended_imm32` with symbol addresses.

Comment: I tried doing `mov rcx, name+8` and then `cmp rsi, rcx` but when I assemble with nasm it simply says `Segmentation fault`. If I remove the +8, it assembles fine. Why is it doing this?

Comment: If I do `mov rcx, name` followed by `add rcx, 8` and `cmp rsi, rcx` it works fine. But why can't I just do `mov rcx, name+8` ?

Comment: What happens when you disassemble the result of using name+8?

Comment: @bdonlan: It's an ABI problem, not a problem with the instructions themselves.  The problem is that `name` is not a constant until runtime.

Comment: @Dietrich, there may be multiple problems, but `CMP` not taking 64-bit immediates is definitely one of them :)

Comment: @bdonlan: Hm, that's strange, because I can assemble the program for x86-64 Linux/ELF without errors.  It appears than nasm is indeed using a 32-bit address.

Comment: @bdonlan: How can I dissasemble if it doesn't generate an executable?

Comment: @Mk12, doesn't `mov rcx, name+8` produce a (crashing) executable? Or does nasm itself crash? If the latter you should probably report a bug to the nasm devs...

Comment: Also, I'd recommend you not link; disassemble the object (.o) file.

Comment: Oh sorry, it does produce an object file.  If I try to link that, I get this error `ld: in hello.o, file too small for architecture x86_64
`. How do i disassemble the object file? for the executable I was using gdb.

Comment: @Mk12, if nasm itself crashes with segmentation fault, there's no point in disassembling, the file's probably corrupted anyway, since nasm died halfway through writing it. But for completeness, `objdump -d` should do it for non-corrupted files. You can pass `-x` as well to dump the headers, including the relocation tables.

Comment: Yeah it must be corrupted, I tried using otool on it and it said it wasn't an object file.

Comment: How come the patch link is a diff between two commits? And your suggestion makes a lot of sense and works great, thanks! Also, how do I assemble with clang?

Comment: `lea rcx, [rel name_end]` would be better than `mov r64, imm64`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem you are facing is simple: the Mach-O format mandates relocatable code, which means that the data has to be accessed not by absolute address but by a relative address.  That is, the assembler can't resolve `name` to a constant because it's *not* a constant, the data could be at any address.

Now that you know that the address of data is relative to the address of your code, see if you can make sense of the output from GCC.  For example,

```
static unsigned global_var;
unsigned inc(void)
{
    return ++global_var;
}

_inc:
    mflr r0                                           ; Save old link register
    bcl 20,31,"L00000000001$pb"                       ; Jump
"L00000000001$pb":
    mflr r10                                          ; Get address of jump
    mtlr r0                                           ; Restore old link register
    addis r2,r10,ha16(_global_var-"L00000000001$pb")  ; Add offset to address
    lwz r3,lo16(_global_var-"L00000000001$pb")(r2)    ; Load global_var
    addi r3,r3,1                                      ; Increment global_var
    stw r3,lo16(_global_var-"L00000000001$pb")(r2)    ; Store global_var
    blr                                               ; Return
```

Note that this is on PowerPC, because I don't know the Mach-O ABI for x86-64.  On PowerPC, you do a jump, saving the program counter, and then do arithmetic on the result.  I believe something completely different happens on x86-64.

(Note: If you look at GCC's assembly output, try looking at it with `-O2`.  I don't bother looking at `-O0` because it's too verbose and more difficult to understand.)

**My recommendation?**  Unless you are writing a compiler (and sometimes even then), write your assembly functions in one of two ways:

- Pass all necessary pointers as arguments to the function, or,
- Write the assembly as inline assembly inside a C function.

This will generally be more portable as well, since you will rely less on certain details of the ABI.  But the ABI is still important!  If you don't know the ABI and follow it, then you'll cause errors that are fairly difficult to detect.  For instance, years ago there was a bug in LibSDL assembly code which caused libc's `memcpy` (also assembly) to copy the wrong data under some very specific circumstances.

Comment: x86-64 Mach-O doesn't have to be position-independent.  If it uses ASLR, it applies text relocations.  The only thing that isn't supported is 32-bit absolute addressing, because the image base where executables are loaded is above 2^32.  (Of course, RIP-relative is generally more efficient that 64-bit absolute on x86-64, so use that except for something like a static array of pointers, e.g. a jump table.)  See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/dynamic_code.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002528-SW2