# Sign or Zero Extension of address in 64bit mode for MOV moffs32?

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, x86-64, memory-address

Let's have an instruction **`MOV EAX,[0xFFFFFFFF]`** encoded in **64bit mode** as **`67A1FFFFFFFF`** (effective address-size is toggled by 67 prefix from default 64 to 32 bits).

Intel's [instruction reference manual](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) (doc Order Number:  325383-057US from December 2015) on page Vol. 2A 2-11 says:

> 2.2.1.3   Displacement
> Addressing in 64-bit mode uses existing 32-bit ModR/M and SIB encodings. The ModR/M and SIB sizes do not change. They
> remain 8 bits or 32 bits and are sign-extended to 64 bits.

This suggests that 32bit displacement should be **sign-extended** but I am not sure if this concerns special moffs addressing mode as well.
On the next page Intel says:

> 2.2.1.6   RIP-Relative Addressing
>
> RIP-relative addressing is enabled by 64-bit mode, not by a 64-bit address-size. The use of the
> address-size prefix  does not disable RIP-relative addressing. The
> effect of the address-size prefix is to truncate and zero-extend the
> computed effective address to 32 bits.

This suggests that in relative addressing mode the disp32 is sign-extended to 64 bit, added to RIP and then truncated and **zero-extended**.
Hovever I am not sure if the same rule applies to absolute addressing mode, which is the case of MOV moffs operations.

**What address will be EAX loaded from, A) FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF or B) 00000000FFFFFFFF ?**

Comment: It's zero extended, so `00000000FFFFFFFF`. Indeed the documentation is unclear, but you can easily test it. You nevertheless got a +1 for doing some research... not many people do that unfortunately.

Comment: @jester I thought you were offering cookies, or was that just for the people who mention the debugger? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`67 A1 FFFFFFFF` isn't using a `disp32` addressing mode, so the Mod/RM section of the documentation doesn't apply.

Intel's x86 manual vol.1 says:

> All 16-bit and **32-bit address calculations are zero-extended** in IA-32e mode to form 64-bit addresses.  Address calculations are first truncated to the effective address size of the current mode (64-bit mode or compatibility mode), as overridden by any address-size prefix. The result is then zero-extended to the full 64-bit address width. [...] A 32-bit address generated in 64-bit mode can access only the low 4 GBytes of the 64-bit mode effective addresses.

This applies to the special [`moffs` absolute addressing forms of `mov`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) as well as to regular ModR/M addressing modes like `mov eax, [edi]` instead of `mov eax, [rdi]`.

Note that the `moffs8/16/32/64` naming shows the operand-size, not the address size (e.g. `mov al, moffs8`).  There isn't a different term for a 32-bit address size `moffs` in 64-bit mode.

The address-size prefix changes the `A1` opcode from a 64-bit immediate address to a 32-bit, i.e. it changes the length of the *rest* of the instruction (unlike ModR/M addressing mode in 64-bit mode, which are always disp0/8/32).  This actually [causes LCP stalls on Skylake, according to my testing](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34733#c3), for `a32  mov  eax, [abs buf]` (NASM chooses to use the moffs encoding for that case, because with the `a32` override specified, it's shorter than ModR/M + disp32)

See also [Does a Length-Changing Prefix (LCP) incur a stall on a simple x86_64 instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65530097/does-a-length-changing-prefix-lcp-incur-a-stall-on-a-simple-x86-64-instruction) for much more detail about LCP stalls in general, including with `67h` address-size prefixes.

---

Anyway, this means that disassembling it as `mov eax, [0xFFFFFFFF]` is wrong (at least in NASM syntax), because that assembles back into an instruction that does something different.

**The correct YASM/[NASM syntax](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo11.html) that will assemble back to that machine code is**

#### `a32  mov eax, [0xFFFFFFFF]`

NASM also accepts `mov eax, [a32 0xFFFFFFFF]`, but YASM doesn't.

---

**GNU `as` also provides a way to express it (without using `.byte`):

`addr32 mov 0xffffffff,%eax`**

```
movl    0x7FFFFFFF, %eax  # 8B mod/rm disp32
movl    0xFFFFFFFF, %eax  # A1 64bit-moffs32: Older GAS versions may have required the movabs mnemonic to force a moffs encoding

movabs  0x7FFFFF, %eax    #     A1 64b-moffs32: movabs forces MOFFS
movabs  0xFFFFFFFF, %rax  # REX A1 64b-moffs64
movabs  0xFFFF, %ax       #  66 A1 64b-moffs64: operand-size prefix

.byte 0x67, 0xa1, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff  # disassembles to  addr32 mov 0xffffffff,%eax
                                          # and that syntax works as assembler input:
addr32 mov 0xffffffff,%eax    # 67 A1 FF FF FF FF:  32b-moffs32
```

---

With NASM/YASM, there's no way to *force* a 32-bit MOFFS encoding in a way that refuses assemble with a register other than AL/AX/EAX/RAX.  `a32 mov [0xfffffff], cl` assembles to `67 88 0c 25   ff ff ff 0f         addr32 mov BYTE PTR ds:0xfffffff,cl` (a ModR/M + disp32 encoding of `mov r/m8, r8`).

You can write `mov eax, [qword 0xffff...]` to get the `moffs64` encoding, but there's no way to require a 32-bit moffs encoding.

---

Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler gets it wrong (disassembling the machine code produced with GNU `as` from the block above).  `objconv` appears to assume sign-extension.   (It puts the machine code in comments as `prefixes: opcode, operands`)

```
; Note: Absolute memory address without relocation
    mov     eax, dword [abs qword 7FFFFFH]          ; 0033 _ A1, 00000000007FFFFF
 ...
; Note: Absolute memory address without relocation
    mov     eax, dword [0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFH]         ; 0056 _ 67: A1, FFFFFFFF
```

**`ndisasm -b64` also disassembles incorrectly, to code that doesn't even work the same way**:

```
00000073  A1FFFF7F00000000  mov eax,[qword 0x7fffff]
         -00
...
00000090  67A1FFFFFFFF      mov eax,[0xffffffff]
```

I would have expected a disassembly like `mov eax, [qword 0xffffffff]`, if it's not going to use the `a32` keyword.  That would assemble to a 64-bit moffs that references the same address as the original, but is longer.  Probably this was overlooked when adding AMD64 support to ndisasm, which already existed before AMD64.

Comment: Indeed, due to zeroing bits 32..63 of destination register with operand-size 32 also should `8BCA` be disassembled as **MOV RCX,EDX**.
Do you think, Peter, that assemblers should accept instructions like **MOV r64,r/m32**  in spite of such operand combination not being declared in reference manuals?

Comment: @vitsoft: It's an interesting suggestion, but introducing it now (as a variant of existing NASM syntax) would be more confusing, not less.  (You'd have to look at all operands to figure out the operand-size of the instruction, not just the first one with an implied size).  AMD could have implemented it that way when they first designed AMD64 syntax, to reinforce the point that zero-extension always happens when writing to a 32bit register.  I think it would only be sane if you disallowed `r32` as a destination operand entirely, though.

Comment: @vitsoft: But then things like `add r64, r/m32` would be confusing, because newbies wouldn't be sure the zero-extension happened to the result, instead of to the src operand.  (i.e. can the add produce a carry into bit 32 of rax?)  Also, it makes `mov r64/m32, imm32` (no REX prefix, operand-size=32, zero-extended constant) vs. `mov r/m64, imm32` (REX prefix, operand-size=64, sign-extended constant) much less clear.  You'd need some kind of syntax to choose between the two forms of `mov rax, -1`.  Interesting idea, but on further consideration it appears to be terrible!

Comment: @vitsoft: update: there is NASM syntax that assembles to `mov eax, moffs32`; see my edit.

Comment: tnx, even more unambiguous NASM syntax is **mov eax,[abs a32 0xFFFFFFFF]**. Nonetheless, degree of freedom in x86 architecture is high and we cannot expect that converting arbitrary binary code to assembler source and assembling it back will always yield the same result.
It is similar to translation from my mother tongue to English and back with Google Translator.
Ad GAS syntax: the **moffs** numeric suffix actually specifies operand-size rather than address-size. Perhaps it should read
`movabs  0x7FFFFF, %eax    #     A1 moffs32: 
`movabs  0xFFFF, %ax       #  66 A1 moffs16: