# ELF - Entry point patching with x86 zero-extended address

Tags: x86-64, elf, shellcode

I've managed patch the entry point of an ELF file and made it point to some place else and execute a piece of code before returning to the original entry point. The following is how I'm trying to jump back to the OEP:

```
mov rax, 0x4141414141414141  ( 48 b8 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 )
jmp rax                      (ff e0)
```

I have an array with these opcodes which I patch as soon as I parse the ELF header to get the entry point:

```
uint64_t oep = ehdr->e_entry;
memcpy(&opcode[23], &oep, 8);
```

But the entry point is always something like: **0x47fe8d** which invalidates the rest of the array since the opcode is expecting an 8 byte address without zeros. I tried to replace it by sign extending the address like: **0xffffffff47fe8d** but it didn't work. This appears to be normal behavior since x86 addresses are [zero-extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665819/sign-or-zero-extension-of-address-in-64bit-mode-for-mov-moffs32).

**EDIT**: The shellcode array looks like this:

```
 _start:
       xor rax, rax
       xor rax, rax
       xor rsi, rsi
       jmp get_str
 shellcode:
       pop rsi
       mov al, 1
       mov dil, 1
       mov dl, 9
       syscall ; writes a string

       mov rax, 0x4141414141414141 ; patched with the EP
       jmp rax
   get_str:
         call shellcode
         db "strings!", 0xa

 // write syscall + jmp OEP (mov rax, addr, jmp rax). patch at 23
unsigned char shellcode[] = "\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xf6\xeb"
                  "\x16\x5e\xb0\x01\x40\xb7\x01\xb2\x09\x0f"
                  "\x05\x48\xb8\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41"
                  "\xff\xe0\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x68\x69\x6a"
                  "\x61\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x0a";
```

I made a function which prints this array before patching it. Here's what it looks like:

```
\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xf6\xeb\x16\x5e\xb0\x01\x40\xb7\x01\xb2\x09\x0f\x05\x48\xb8\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\xff\xe0\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x68\x69\x6a\x61\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x0a
```

But after patching the **jmp** instruction with 0x47fe8d the higher bytes of the address become zero:

```
\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xf6\xeb\x16\x5e\xb0\x01\x40\xb7\x01\xb2\x09\x0f\x05\x48\xb8\x20\x1b\x40
```

And this for some reason causes a segmentation fault. I used IDA to search for the entry point of the patched file and here's what I found:

```
LOAD:000000000047FE8D start:                                  ; DATA XREF: LOAD:0000000000400018↑o
LOAD:000000000047FE8D                 xor     rax, rax
LOAD:000000000047FE90                 xor     rdi, rdi
LOAD:000000000047FE93                 xor     rsi, rsi
LOAD:000000000047FE96
LOAD:000000000047FE96 loc_47FE96:                             ; CODE XREF: LOAD:000000000047FEAC↓j
LOAD:000000000047FE96                 jmp     short loc_47FEAE
LOAD:000000000047FE98 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOAD:000000000047FE98                 pop     rsi
LOAD:000000000047FE99                 mov     al, 1
LOAD:000000000047FE9B                 mov     dil, 1
LOAD:000000000047FE9E                 mov     dl, 9
LOAD:000000000047FEA0                 syscall                 ; $!
LOAD:000000000047FEA2                 mov     rax, offset _start
LOAD:000000000047FEAC                 loopne  loc_47FE96
LOAD:000000000047FEAE
LOAD:000000000047FEAE loc_47FEAE:                             ; CODE XREF: LOAD:loc_47FE96↑j
LOAD:000000000047FEAE                 in      eax, 0FFh       ; $!
LOAD:000000000047FEAE ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOAD:000000000047FEB0                 dq 6B63616A6968FFFFh
LOAD:000000000047FEB8                 db 65h, 64h, 0Ah
LOAD:000000000047FEB8 LOAD            ends
```

So, despite IDA wrongly encoding the instruction at **000000000047FEAC** it appears that the file has been successfully patched, the _start symbol leads to the following path:

```
public _start
_start proc near
endbr64
xor     ebp, ebp
mov     r9, rdx         ; rtld_fini
pop     rsi             ; argc
mov     rdx, rsp        ; ubp_av
and     rsp, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0h
push    rax
push    rsp             ; stack_end
mov     r8, offset __libc_csu_fini ; fini
mov     rcx, offset __libc_csu_init ; init
mov     rdi, offset main ; main
db      67h
call    __libc_start_main
hlt
_start endp
```

This ends up calling the original main function, everything seems to be in order.

Upon further examination I found out that the instruction at **000000000047FEAE** is the culprit, although I don't really understand why.
This is the **call** instruction I used to push the address of the string onto the stack.

Why am I  getting a Segmentation fault?

Comment: The ELF entry point is a 64-bit address, not using 32-bit address-size prefixes to truncate + zero-extend back to 64 bits.  Are you talking about shellcode?  If you need to create a value in a register that contains zeros, you can do that with something like `mov rax, (-1) ^ 0x47fe8d` ; `not rax`: i.e. use immediate constants that don't contain zero, then XOR or subtract something to get the value you want in a register.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes Peter, I have updated the question with a few more details.

Comment: What exactly causes a segfault?  The program running the shellcode, or the patched binary?  Use a debugger to see what instruction faults.  Those code blocks of hex strings are basically useless to most people without including disassembly.

Comment: @PeterCordes according to gdb it's crashing at **000000000047FEAE** which is when I use the **call** instruction to get the string onto the stack.For some reason IDA has decoded it wrong.

Comment: **IDA isn't decoding it wrong, your hex string is wrong**.  That's how it disassembles for me if I compile that C array into a `.o` and disassemble it with `objdump -D -rwC -Mintel foo.o` to get objdump to disassemble the `.data` section.  You should also see the same thing if you disassemble within GDB on the instruction that faulted; it's probably the `in` instruction which is privileged.  (Why is this even shellcode in a char array in the first place instead of just a function written in asm, assembled into a `.o`, and linked into your program?)

Comment: @PeterCordes well, that's odd. The way I came up with this array was by using:  **nasm -f elf64** with a **.s** file containing  the assembly instructions. Using objdump on the **.o** file I don't get an **in** instruction but rather it decodes it as **imul**(I assume it's because objdump is trying to make sense of the string bytes)

Comment: @PeterCordes I have tried some other shellcodes like call exit, fork and they all seem to work. As for the hex string being wrong, I don't think that's the case here. `objdump -d` is  showing exactly the same bytes I used.

Comment: I think you're one `0x41` short in your string.  `objdump -d` for me shows `48 b8 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 ff` - the most significant byte of your `mov` imm64 is the FF that's supposed to be the `jmp` opcode.  Your C string only has 7 `\x41` bytes.

Comment: @PeterCordes you're right! I missed that somehow. Thanks Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IDA isn't decoding it wrong, your hex string version of your machine code is wrong**; one `\x41` byte short so `mov r64, imm64` consumes the following `FF` byte as part of its immediate, instead of the opcode for `jmp`.  That's why it decodes at `0e e8` loopne`.

I noticed this by copy/pasting your C array into a `.c` and compiling that into a `.o`.  Then I disassembled it with `objdump -D -rwC -Mintel foo.o` to get objdump to disassemble the .data section.  It agrees with IDA, proving IDA was right and you did make a mistake in whatever you did to translate your NASM output into a hex string.  (IDK why you're bothering to do that, instead of just linking with the NASM `.o` output to test it the normal way first, or what it has to do with modifying an ELF binary.)

```
 // write syscall + jmp OEP (mov rax, addr, jmp rax). patch at 23
unsigned char shellcode[] = "\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xf6\xeb"
                  "\x16\x5e\xb0\x01\x40\xb7\x01\xb2\x09\x0f"
                  "\x05\x48\xb8\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41"  // this is only 7 x41 bytes
                  "\xff\xe0\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x68\x69\x6a"
                  "\x61\x63\x6b\x65\x64\x0a";
```

`objdump -D` shows `48 b8 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 ff  movabs rax,0xff41414141414141` - the most significant byte of your `mov` imm64 is the FF that's supposed to be the `jmp` opcode.  Your C string only has 7 `\x41` bytes.

You should also see the same thing if you disassemble within GDB on the instruction that faulted; it's probably the `in` instruction which is privileged.

---

#### Creating values that contain `0` in registers with shellcode

This part is easy.  XOR or ADD some constant like `-1` or `0x80` that makes every byte non-zero, then NOT, xor-immediate, or sub-immediate.  Or pad with low garbage and right shift.

e.g. to create 3-byte `0x47fe8d` in a register, you can do

```
   mov eax, 0x47fe8d61       ; (0x47fe8d << 8) + 'a'
   shr eax, 8
```

Writing a 32-bit register implicitly zero-extends to 64 bits, so this leaves
RAX = `0 0 0 0   0 47 fe 8d` = `0x47fe8d`.

Or

```
    mov eax, ~0x47fe8d          ; none of the bytes are FF -> none of ~x are 0
    not eax                     ; still leaving the upper 32 bits zeroed
```