# Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm, mach-o

Running this code off my Mac computer, using command:

```
nasm -f macho64 -o max.a maximum.asm
```

This is the code I am attempting to run on my computer that finds the largest number inside an array.

```
section .data

data_items:
    dd 3,67,34,222,45,75,54,34,44,33,22,11,66,0

    section .text

global _start

_start:
    mov edi, 0
    mov eax, [data_items + edi*4]
    mov ebx, eax

start_loop:
    cmp eax, 0
    je loop_exit
    inc edi
    mov eax, [data_items + edi*4]
    cmp eax, ebx
    jle start_loop

mov ebx, eax
jmp start_loop

loop_exit:

mov eax, 1
int 0x80
```

Error:

```
maximum.asm:14: error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses
maximum.asm:21: error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses
```

Comment: First question you need to ask yourself. Am I trying to make a 32-bit program or a 64-bit program?

Answer (score 14):

First of all, **beware of NASM bugs with the macho64 output format** with [64-bit absolute addressing (NASM 2.13.02+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224997/successive-sys-write-syscalls-not-working-as-expected-nasm-bug-on-os-x) and with [RIP-relative in NASM 2.11.08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469149/nasm-compiling-x86-64-asm-label-addresses-off-by-256-bytes-in-mach-o-when-using).  64-bit absolute addressing is not recommended, so this answer should work even for buggy NASM 2.13.02 and higher.  (The bugs don't cause this error, they lead to wrong addresses being used at runtime.)

---

`[data_items + edi*4]` is a 32-bit addressing mode.  Even `[data_items + rdi*4]` can only use a 32-bit absolute displacement, so it wouldn't work either.  Note that using an address as a 32-bit (sign-extended) immediate like [`cmp rdi, data_items` is also a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577482/assembler-error-mach-o-64-bit-does-not-support-absolute-32-bit-addresses): only `mov` allows a 64-bit immediate.

**64-bit code on OS X can't use 32-bit absolute addressing at all**.  Executables are loaded at a base address above 4GiB, so label addresses just plain don't fit in 32-bit integers, with zero- or sign-extension.  RIP-relative addressing is the best / most efficient solution, whether you need it to be position-independent or not<sup>1</sup>.

**In NASM, [`default rel`](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.2) at the top of your file** will make all `[]` memory operands prefer RIP-relative addressing.  See also [Section 3.3 Effective Addresses](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3) in the NASM manual.

```
default rel                     ; near the top of file; affects all instructions

my_func:
    ...
    mov   ecx, [data_items]         ; uses the default: RIP-relative

    ;mov  ecx, [abs data_items]     ; override to absolute [disp32], unusuable
    mov   ecx, [rel data_items]     ; explicitly RIP-relative
```

But RIP-relative [is only possible when there are no other registers involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes/34058400#34058400), so **for indexing a static array you need to get the address in a register first**.  Use a RIP-relative `lea rsi, [rel data_items]`.

```
 lea   rsi, [data_items]    ; can be outside the loop
 ...
 mov   eax, [rsi + rdi*4]
```

Or you could `add rsi, 4` inside the loop and use a simpler addressing mode like `mov eax, [rsi]`.

Note that `mov rsi, data_items` will work for getting an address into a register, but you don't want that because it's less efficient.

Technically, any address within +-2GiB of your array will work, so if you have multiple arrays you can address the others relative to one common base address, only tieing up one register with a pointer.  e.g. `lea rbx, [arr1]` / ... / `mov eax, [rbx + rdi*4 + arr2-arr1]`.  [Relative Addressing errors - Mac 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927278/relative-addressing-errors-mac-10-10) mentions that Agner Fog's "optimizing assembly" guide has some examples of array addressing, including one using the `__mh_execute_header` as a reference point.  (The code in that question looks like another attempt to port this 32-bit Linux example from the PGU book to 64-bit OS X, at the same time as learning asm in the first place.)

---

Note that on Linux, position-dependent executables are loaded in the low 32 bits of virtual address space, so you will see code like `mov eax, [array + rdi*4]` or `mov edi, symbol_name` in Linux examples or compiler output on http://gcc.godbolt.org/.  `gcc -pie -fPIE` will make position-independent executables on Linux, and [is the default on many recent distros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux), but not Godbolt.

This doesn't help you on MacOS, but I mention it in case anyone's confused about code they've seen for other OSes, or why AMD64 architects bothered to allow `[disp32]` addressing modes at all on x86-64.

---

And BTW, **prefer using 64-bit addressing modes in 64-bit code**.  e.g. use `[rsi + rdi*4]`, not `[esi + edi*4]`.  You usually don't want to truncate pointers to 32-bit, and it costs an extra address-size prefix to encode.

Similarly, you should be using `syscall` to make 64-bit system calls, not `int 0x80`.  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64) for the differences in which registers to pass args in.

---

**Footnote 1:** 
64-bit absolute addressing is supported on OS X, but only in position-dependent executables (non-PIE).  This related question [x64 nasm: pushing memory addresses onto the stack & call function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091987/x64-nasm-pushing-memory-addresses-onto-the-stack-call-function) includes an `ld` warning from using `gcc main.o` to link:

```
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not
allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from main.o. To fix this warning,
don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
```

So the linker checks if any 64-bit absolute relocations are used, and if so disables creation of a Position-Independent Executable.  A PIE can benefit from [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) for security.  I think shared-library code always has to be position-independent on OS X; I don't know if jump tables or other cases of pointers-as-data are allowed (i.e. fixed up by the dynamic linker), or if they need to be initialized at runtime if you aren't making a position-dependent executable.

`mov r64, imm64` is larger (10 bytes) and not faster than `lea r64, [RIP_rel32]` (7 bytes).

So you *could* use `mov rsi, qword data_items` instead of a RIP-relative LEA which runs about as fast, and takes less space in code caches and the uop cache.  64-bit immediates also have a uop-cache fetch penalty for on Sandybridge-family (http://agner.org/optimize/): they take 2 cycles to read from a uop cache line instead of 1.

x86 also has a form of `mov` that loads/store from/to a 64-bit absolute address, but only for AL/AX/EAX/RAX.  See http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html.  You don't want this either, because it's larger and not faster than `mov eax, [rel foo]`.

---

(Related: [an AT&T syntax version of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205129/unable-to-move-variables-in-data-to-registers-with-mac-x86-assembly))

Comment: Update, apparently OS X doesn't require PIE (position independent executables), it just uses an image base above 32 bits.  So you *could* use `mov r64, imm64` to put addresses into registers, but don't because RIP-relative LEA is better.

Comment: Or for non-indexed loads, you could use `movabs eax, [foo]` (the AT&T mnemonic for the [`mov al/ax/eax/rax, moffs` form of `mov`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) with a 64-bit absolute address instead of a ModR/M addressing mode.  But again, don't do that because a RIP-relative addressing mode is more compact and just as efficient.