# How do you `mov` a label to a register in x86_64 intel gas assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, gnu-assembler

In x86_64 intel nasm assembly you can do

```
label: .asciz "Something\n"
mov rsi, label
```

and it will generate

```
movabs rsi,0x201000
```

If you use x86_64 intel with gas and write

```
label: .asciz "Something\n"
mov rsi, label
```

it will generate

```
mov    rsi, qword ptr [0x6000db]
```

which just loads the literal ascii values for the string "Something" into `rsi` instead of the address for it.

I've tried about a dozen different permutations and can't figure out how replicate the nasm output in gas.

Note: I know I can use lea, mov with rip-relative etc. I'm not asking for a way to get this code to work, I'm asking how to replicate the results from the nasm output.

Comment: You can find out how to do something in GAS syntax by looking at compiler output.  e.g. `int var;
int *foo() { return &var; }` compiles to `mov   eax, OFFSET FLAT:var` https://godbolt.org/g/oH6eH8

Comment: Thanks! But didn't quite work. `movabs esi, offset label` did, however.

Comment: Are you on OS X or something?  Or building PIE executables on Linux?  Either way, if `mov esi, OFFSET var` doesn't work, use `lea rsi, [RIP+var]`.  A 64-bit absolute immediate is not efficient, so the OFFSET keyword is usually only *useful* when you can use an address as a 32-bit immediate.  [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47300844) and the footnote in [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427).