# How can I compare the first character of a string with another character in x86-64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have an initialized string "Hello, World!" from which I would like to extract the first character (i.e. 'H') and comapre it a character that is passed into a register at run time.

I have tried comparing the first character of "Hello, World!" with 'H' through the following code:

```
global start

section .data
msg: db "Hello, World!", 10, 0

section .text
start:
   mov rdx, msg
   mov rdi, [rdx]
   mov rsi, 'H'
   cmp rdi, rsi
   je equal

   mov rax, 0x2000001
   mov rdi, [rdx]
   syscall

equal:
   mov rax, 0x2000001
   mov rdi, 58
   syscall
```

However, this code terminates without jumping to the `equal` label. Moreover, the exit status of my program is `72`, which is the ASCII code for `H`. This made me try to pass `72` into `rsi` instead of `H`, but that too resulted in a program the terminates without jumping to the `equal` label.

How can I properly compare the first character in "Hello, World!" with a character that is passed to a register?

Comment: You should use byte register parts like `al` and `ah`, not the full-width registers. The cmp is comparing the entire register values. Plus, `rdi` has more than one character. Stepping through a debugger like gdb can help you solve these kind of issues on your own and increase your understanding.

Comment: @Rafael Could you provide a code example of how I should use byte register parts? I am very new to assembly and have never encountered `al` and `ah`.

Comment: Those three MOV / CMP instructions should be something like `mov al, [rdx], mov ah, 'H', cmp al, ah`

Comment: or simply use `movzx rdi, BYTE [rdx]`

Comment: @Rafael Thanks. Your solutions works perfectly. If you don't mind, could you explain why using these registers works, but my implementation doesn't?

Comment: Use `default rel` and use `cmp byte [msg], 'H'`.  Or if you want the pointer in RDI so you can increment it in a loop, use `lea rdi, [rel msg]`.  You normally never want to use `mov rdi, msg` with a 64-bit immediate of the absolute address.  [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47300844)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain the changes side-by-side (hopefully that's easier to follow):

```
global start

section .data
msg: db "Hello, World!", 10, 0

section .text
start:
   mov rdx, msg
   mov al, [rdx] ; moves one byte from msg, H to al, the 8-bit lower part of ax
   mov ah, 'H'   ; move constant 'H' to the 8-bit upper part of ax
   cmp al, ah    ; compares H with H
   je equal      ; yes, they are equal, so go to address at equal

   mov rax, 0x2000001
   mov rdi, [rdx]
   syscall

equal:           ; here we are
   mov rax, 0x2000001
   mov rdi, 58
   syscall
```

If you're not understanding the use / mention of `al`, `ah`, `ax`, please see [General-Purpose Registers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#General-purpose_registers_(64-bit_naming_conventions)).

Answer (score 4):

You and @Rafael's answer are massively over-complicating your code.

You normally never want to use `mov rdi, msg` with a 64-bit immediate of the absolute address.  (See [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47300844))

Use `default rel` and use `cmp byte [msg], 'H'`.  Or if you want the pointer in RDI so you can increment it in a loop, use `lea rdi, [rel msg]`.

The only thing that's different between your branches is the RDI value.  You don't need to duplicate the RAX setup or the `syscall`, just get the right value in RDI and then have the branches rejoin each other.  (Or do it branchlessly.)

@Rafael's answer is still loading 8 bytes from the string for some reason, like both loads in your question.  Presumably this is `sys_exit` and it ignores the upper bytes, only setting process exit status from the low byte, but just for fun let's pretend we actually want all 8 bytes loaded for the syscall while only comparing the low byte.

```
default rel         ; use RIP-relative addressing modes by default for [label]
global start

section .rodata                       ;; read-only data usually belongs in .rodata
msg: db "Hello, World!", 10, 0

section .text
start:
   mov   rdi, [msg]    ; 8 byte load from a RIP-relative address
   mov   ecx, 'H'

   cmp   dil, cl       ; compare the low byte of RDI (dil) with the low byte of RCX (cl)
   jne   .notequal
   ;; fall through on equal
   mov   edi, 58
.notequal:             ; .labels are local labels in NASM

   ; mov rdi, [rdx]    ; still loaded from before; we didn't destroy it.
   mov eax, 0x2000001
   syscall
```

Avoid writing to AH/BH/CH/DH when possible.  It either has a false dependency on the old value of RAX/RBX/RCX/RDX, or it can cause partial-register merging stalls if you later read the full register.  @Rafael's answer doesn't do that, but the `mov ah, 'H'` is dependent on the load into AL on some CPUs.  See [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) and [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to) - `mov ah, 'H'` has a false dependency on the old value of AH on Haswell/Skylake, even though AH is renamed separately from RAX.  But AL isn't, so yes, this might well have a false dependency on the load, stopping it from running in parallel and delaying the `cmp` by a cycle.

Anyway, the TL:DR here is that you shouldn't mess around with writing AH/BH/CH/DH if you don't need to.  Reading them is often ok, but can have worse latency.  And note that `cmp dil, ah` isn't encodeable, because DIL is only accessible with a REX prefix and AH is only accessible without.

I picked RCX instead of RSI because CL doesn't need a REX prefix, but since we need to look at the low byte of RDI (dil) we need a REX prefix anyway on the cmp.  I could have use `mov cl, 'H'` to save code-size, because there's probably no problem with a false dependency on the old value of RCX.

---

BTW, `cmp dil, 'H'` would work just as well as `cmp dil, cl`.

Or if we load the byte with zero-extension into the full RDI, we can use `cmp edi, 'H'` instead of the low-8 version of it.  (**Zero-extending loads are the normal / recommended way to deal with bytes and 16-bit integers on modern x86-64.**  Merging into the low byte of the old register value is usually worse for performance, which is the reason [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6).)

And instead of branching, we could CMOV.  This is sometimes better, sometimes not, for code-size and performance.

**Version 2, only actually loading 1 byte:**

```
start:
   movzx   edi, byte [msg]    ; 1 byte load, zero extended to 4 (and implicitly to 8)

   mov     eax, 58            ; ASCII ':'
   cmp     edi, 'H'
   cmove   edi, eax           ; edi =  (edi == 'H') ? 58 : edi

   ; rdi = 58 or the first byte,
   ; unlike in the other version where it had 8 bytes of string data here
   mov eax, 0x2000001
   syscall
```

(This version *looks* a lot shorter, but most of the extra lines were whitespace, comments, and labels.  Optimizing to `cmp`-immediate makes this 4 instructions instead of 5 before the `mov eax` / `syscall`, but other than that they're equal.)