# Store ,,procedures" in a table in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, position-independent-code, jump-table

Suppose I have a *table* in .rodata which would store procedure offsets, so I can use:

```
call [table + index]
```

in order to call the procedure defined in my code. Is it possible to achieve in PIC? How can I find these offsets and create such a table?

Comment: Store relative offsets and add them to RIP.  Related: [Jump table implementation in MASM x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57571027) although my answer there has extra levels of indirection (because I think the question did) so it's weird and over-complicated.  And it's assuming that you can have 64-bit absolute addresses in static data, which you normally can with runtime fixups; `.quad target1, target2` etc. should just work with normal toolchains, although it does require runtime relocation.

Comment: See [GCC Jump Table initialization code generating movsxd and add?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52190313) for how GCC does it in x86-64 PIE executables (position-independent).  You can write it yourself with `foo: dd target1 - foo, target2 - foo` and so on, where `foo` is the anchor point you use for a RIP-relative LEA.  (Or in 32-bit PIC code, use whatever anchor point you generate with a call/pop.)