# Error format doest not support 32-bit absolute addresses

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, mach-o

I'm working on a project in `ASM x86-64` on a mac with the last version of catalina. When I try to compile it, I got tihs error `error: Macho-O 64-bit format doest not support 32-bit absolute adresses`. I got this when I try to move an adress in the stack frame.

Example:

```
my_fnc:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 64
    mov qword [rbp - 8], __zpair
....
....
....

section .rodata

__zpair:
    db "pair", 0
```

Comment: See also [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47301555/417501).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only space for 32 bits in most immediate operands.  `__zpair`, being a 64 bit address, might not fit<sup>†</sup> which is why the assembler rejects this code.  Use

```
lea rax, [rel __zpair]  ; load the address of __zpair
mov [rbp - 8], rax      ; write address to stack
```

to first load the address using a `rip`-relative addressing mode and then write it into the stack frame.

---

† Contrary to other platforms, macOS does not guarantee that your executable will be loaded into the first 2 GB of memory.  In fact, it will never do so unless specifically configured.

Comment: And more importantly, Mach-O doesn't have relocations for 32-bit absolute addresses, so NASM has no way of telling the linker to even make an attempt to do that.