# Why is there and error/warning when compiling .o file using ld command on mac?

Tags: macos, assembly, compilation, nasm, ld

I learning assembly language, and I have used 'nasm' to compile my .asm file called 'my_program' to a .o file using this command here:

```
nasm -f elf32 my_program.asm -o my_program.o
```

As far as I am concerned, this works fine, as a .o file is created. I then do this command:

```
ld my_program.o -o my_program
```

Instead of creating a unix executable like it should, this warning/error appears:

```
ld: warning: platform not specified
ld: warning: -arch not specified
ld: warning: No platform min-version specified on command line
ld: warning: ignoring file my_program.o, building for -unknown but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 )
Undefined symbols for architecture unknown:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture unknown
```

Does anyone have any clue why this is happening? Here is the assembly code in the .asm file if it helps (I am just following a tutorial):

```
global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 42
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Your tutorial is for GNU/Linux, which uses ELF object files instead of `macho`, and a slightly different system-call ABI.  Find a Mac tutorial or run it on actual Linux in a VM.  **Don't try to port your tutorial to MacOS while you're still trying to learn the super-basics from it.**

Comment: This code is 32-bit Linux code which passes arguments in registers. 32-bit MacOS/reeBSD uses the stack. MacOS tool chain uses Macho (for 32-bit Mach it is Macho32), not elf. What happens if you use `-f macho32` with NASM instead of `-f elf32` . It is also possible you are on a MacOS that doesn't even support directly creating or running 32-bit programs anymore.That would be the case if you were using MacOS Catalina or newer OS.

Comment: Ah I see! What is the difference between elf32 and macho32? Also if Mac does not support 32-bit programs, then would the flag be macho64?

Comment: If on a 64-bit only system you'd have to use macho64 and use the proper 64-bit calling convention for system calls. http://www.idryman.org/blog/2014/12/02/writing-64-bit-assembly-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: I tries tried running these two commands:
```
% nasm -f macho32 my_program.asm -o my_program.o
% ld my_program.o -o my_program
```
...and I get this error:
```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Comment: Ok, what will that do?

Comment: Try telling `ld` that your entry point is `_start` with the ld command line option `-e _start`

Comment: Go look for a 64-bit NASM tutorial for MacOS and use that instead.  I forget if https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info lists any; let me know if you find a good one. (Although beware of NASM bugs on MacOS ([this answer mentions both recent well-known ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47301555/224132)); `as` with `.intel_syntax noprefix` might be a better choice). It will have the right commands for assembling and linking.  Like I said, don't try to port a 32-bit Linux tutorial to MacOS until after you've already learned most of what it's trying to teach.  Then hopefully it will be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `_start` function to `_main`, the linker expects a `_main` function just like C++/C expects `int main()` for `.cpp`/`.c`

```
global _main
_main:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 42
    int 0x80
```

Comment: And you've tested this on MacOS with what `nasm` and `ld` commands?  The OP was using `nasm -felf32` which is likely going to be a problem on MacOS that expects Mach-O object files.  Also, IIRC MacOS's 32-bit `int 0x80` system call ABI matches FreeBSD's - it expects args on the stack, starting with `[esp+4]`.  So if you did get this to link, it might exit correctly, but it would `_exit(argc)` instead of the `_exit(42)` the code intends.