# how to use MASM (intel assembly) on Mac

Tags: macos, assembly, intel, masm

I've got an assembly Course (I'm a computer science student) that require from us to use only MASM (intel assembly). I am using Mac OS and I can't understand how to do so throw the terminal.

I looked at some guides but no one works correctly on my computer ( I have 11.2.2 version on my Mac)

please someone can give me the specified and simple instruction to do this please ????

I'm pretty lost...

thank you

Comment: I don't think MASM can output into formats other than Windows COFF.  It's certainly not the only Intel-syntax assembler, for example NASM is portable (including MacOS), but it's had multiple bugs with the Mach-O64 output format.  The top of [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47300844) links both of them.  But anyway, if you *have* to use MASM, presumably you have to write code that calls Windows functions.  If you instead make MacOS system calls, your code won't work for your instructor when they test it.

Comment: thanks!  there is different in the syntax between them? do you think it will work the same if I will use NASM instead of MASM? or the smartest thing to do is to install and use windows with VM ?

Comment: If you want to write Windows programs (e.g. with the Irvine32 library), then yes, although you might be able to use JWASM and WINE if you're targeting 32-bit Windows.  (Yes, NASM and MASM have different syntax.  JWASM is an open-source assembler that can accept MASM syntax, I think.).

Comment: Are you using a Mac with an Intel processor, or one with the new M1?

Comment: yes they told us to install that Irvine 32 library, and I have intel processor. I bought my MacBook at 2019.

Comment: do you know any good instruction or guid to install JWASM and WINE? because some of the guid told me to install WINE, but in order to do this they asked to install dosbox that isn't worked for me...

Comment: dosbox makes no sense.  I don't have a Mac, but you'd want to be making native Windows executables, not DOS.  I've never used JWASM.