# Relocation error happening locally but not in godbolt

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, relocation, compiler-explorer

Consider this program on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Krz1hvv75):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>

int64_t const x[] = { 42, 2, 3, 4 };

int64_t f() {
  int64_t i;
  asm volatile (
    "xor %[i], %[i]\n\t"
    "movq _ZL1x(,%[i],8), %[i]"
  : [i]"=r"(i));
  return i;
}

int64_t g() {
  int64_t i;
  asm volatile (
    "xor %[i], %[i]"
  : [i]"=r"(i));
  i = x[i];
  return i;
}

int main() {
  assert(f() == 42);
}
```

It compiles, links and runs fine for gcc 13.1 but clang 16.0 gives a linker error:

```
[...]: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.cst32' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
```

If I try the same code locally and compile it with `g++ -O3 main.cpp` (same gcc version) I get the same error above. (Recompiling with `-fPIE` doesn't fix.)

It's worth noticing that the code generated by gcc for `f()` and `g()` are identical:

```
_Z1fv:
  xor %rax, %rax
  movq _ZL1x(,%rax,8), %rax
  ret
_Z1gv:
  xor %rax, %rax
  movq _ZL1x(,%rax,8), %rax
  ret
```

and if I remove `f` from the source file and use `g` in `main`, then all compilers are happy, locally and on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/93MEMds5G).

I understand that directly writing `_ZL1x` in my inline assembly is weird and very likely to be a bad practice but that's not the point here. I would like to know why gcc is happy on godbolt and not locally and, more importantly, how could I make it to work locally and (if possible) for clang as well.

Comment: Add `-no-pie`. Presumably godbolt does not default to PIE.

Comment: If you change the godbolt compiler to `x86-64 clang 16.0.0` you get the same error.  By turning off the setting for `Execute the code`, you can see the generated asm.  No doubt the problem stems from `leaq _ZL1x(%rip), %rcx`.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Godbolt's install of clang 16 is configured with `-fPIE -pie` as the default, for some reason, unlike all its other x86 compilers.  But that is how Linux distros have configured gcc/clang for several years now: See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)

Comment: If you locally did `gcc -O3 -S`, you could see the PIE-compatible asm it made for your `g()` function, using a RIP-relative LEA first.  Also, you could use `extern "C"` to have it not name-mangle your `const int64_t x[]` array, so the asm symbol name would just be `x`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the link. It's very useful.

Comment: I'm considering reopening this to answer about how GCC/Clang are configured on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer vs. in typical distros (`-fPIE -pie -fstack-protector-strong` on by default, along with perhaps `-fno-plt`.)  As someone who just ran into this issue, would the duplicate alone have answered it, without the comments here?

Comment: @PeterCordes I think this would be useful. I only felt that my question was answered by the collection of comments and the answers to other posts. I'll also be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Most Linux distros configure GCC and Clang with `-fPIE -pie -fstack-protector-strong` on by default**, and perhaps `-fno-plt`.  So they're making Position-Independent Executables that have to be relocatable to anywhere in 64-bit address-space.

Matt Godbolt's **Compiler Explorer has compilers installed with their vanilla configuration**, with none of those options on by default, so they're making traditional executables that get linked to a specific address in the low 31 bits of virtual address space.  (Except x86-64 Clang 16.0 which has at least `-fPIE` enabled.  This is purely up to the sysadmins of https://godbolt.org/ using the default config options when building compilers from source.)

---

Any addressing mode other than `symbol(%rip)` uses at most a 32-bit sign-extended displacement<sup>1</sup>, so an absolute address has to fit into that.  That only works in a Linux non-PIE executable, and I think a Windows non-LargeAddressAware executable or dll.  Not in MachO64 no matter how you link it.

**If you locally did `gcc -O3 -S`, you could see the PIE-compatible asm it made for your `g()` function, using a RIP-relative LEA first.**

See

- [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) - because of PIE becoming the default, with lots of details about that and GCC options.
- [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register) - RIP-relative LEA syntax, along with why 32-bit absolute works in non-PIE Linux executables, so compilers will use `mov $x, %edi` when they want an address in RDI.
- [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300844/mach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute-addresses-nasm-accessing) - indexing arrays in position-independent code using a RIP-relative LEA and `movq x(%[tmp],%[i],8), %[i])`.  That Q&A uses NASM syntax, not GAS AT&T or Intel.

---

> (Recompiling with `-fPIE` doesn't fix.)

That error message is assuming the machine code was generated by a *compiler* from a `.c`, not just *assembled* from hand-written asm.  With hand-written asm, there is no compilation step, only assembling.  Or, you the human are the "compiler", so you need to position-independent asm to implement the algorithm that exists in your brain.  (64-bit absolute addresses are also allowed, with the dynamic linker applying a text-relocation fixup on load, but RIP-relative addressing is efficient.)

---

Footnote 1: Except the special 64-bit absolute addressing mode for load/store of the accumulator, like `movabs foo, %eax`, which is less compact than RIP-relative so you don't want it if you're building normal code where static data is within +-2GiB of code.  There's a reason compilers don't use it.

Comment: Regarding the name mangling, to my utmost surprise, your suggestion does't work. The rules on whether to mangle or not are different for variables and functions. For variables, `const`, `static`, `extern` seem more relevant than `extern "C"`. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/YxzKGGcrb).

Comment: @CassioNeri: Oh, it's the `extern`, not the `"C"`, that disabled name-mangling when I tested with `extern "C" int const x[] = {...}`.   https://godbolt.org/z/qaM6njsYz .  I knew global variable names weren't normally mangled in the C++ ABI used on Linux, but didn't realize that didn't apply to non-const.  I'll just remove that from the answer, then.